# Uploading .pfx file to Azure with 0 bytes

Tags: azure, pfx, azure-api-apps, xero-api

I'm trying to upload a .pfx file (which is 0 bytes) for authenticating an API app on Azure, but I'm having trouble meeting the file the file constraints requiring it to be atleast 1 byte.  Anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: So.....it's an invalid PFX file?  I'd think that even if you got around the restriction of the file actually having content, if the file isn't a valid PFX then it'll still get rejected.  I think you need to expand on what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying to create an API app, which is requiring me to generate an RSA Private Key and Public key which is used for authentication.  I'm pretty new to all of this... I regenerated the keys and it worked fine.  I pretty sure I miss entered in the passphrase the first time.